# Generics with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to implement a notifications system with the assistance of Entity Framework (Database First):

[image: EF Diagram]

As you can see LogNotification and EmailNotification inherit from Notification.  Notification will be an abstract class, with a Deliver(); method, like this:

```
public abstract partial class Notification
{
    public abstract void Deliver();
}
```

The above code is insufficient for use however, because each notification requires some sort of runtime context that it may wish to notify of (for example, if the "Event" is that a payment has been made, then the notification would need to know about who was paid and how much etc), so I was thinking I need something more like this:

```
public abstract partial class Notification<TContext>
{
    public abstract void Deliver(TContext context);
}
```

My main problem is that Notification< TContext > is a different class to the Notification class generated by Entity Framework, so I'm not extending the EF entity here.  Is there any way to get Entity Framework to generate entities with generic parameters?  What alternatives are there to achieve what I'm looking for besides a "Deliver(object context)" method?

Comment: I think that your class should be non-generic and that `TContext` should be replaced with an interface.

Comment: ...A generic interface? Or not? I can't envisage a non-generic interface that would help here.  And implementing a generic interface would still need the Notification class to become a Notification<T> class.

Comment: EF4.5 doesn't handle generics (or Interfaces and enums for that matter).  They added support in EF5 for enums (not sure about Interfaces), but to get enum support, you needed to move to .Net 4.5.  I haven't checked EF6, but I doubt it supports generics.  How would you create a table that you don't have any information about and could practically be anything?

Comment: Table creation doesn't need to know about the type parameters, but at runtime code might use methods on the class that use the type parameters.  For creation of a rich domain model, I can see generics being desirable.